# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lab02pc19

Tags: android, bluetooth

I know there are many equal to the problems but none of the many who have read is equal to mine or has worked for me for help , so it is going to require your help.
I'm working on an application with a NavigationDrawer , I need to make an image work for me on and off the bluetooth cell .
I made another code separately with an " empty activity" and if I worked, but in the navigariondrawe that is where I need it to work , but it does not work , I 've tried many things , but I hope you can help me .

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2, PID: 5146
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2/com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2.MainActivity.setImagenBluetooth(MainActivity.java:69)
at com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```html
package com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentBlue.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
     ImageView miimagen;
    BluetoothAdapter adaptador_bluetooth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        miimagen= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivw);
        adaptador_bluetooth= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(adaptador_bluetooth==null)
        {
         miimagen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
         setImagenBluetooth(adaptador_bluetooth.isEnabled());
        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    public void clickImagen(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {

            case R.id.ivw:
                setEstadoBluetooth();
                break;

        }

    }
    public void miimagen()
    {
        setEstadoBluetooth();
    }

    public void setImagenBluetooth(boolean valor)
    {
     if(valor)miimagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetooth);

    }

    public void setEstadoBluetooth()
    {
        if(adaptador_bluetooth.isEnabled())
        {
         setImagenBluetooth(false);
            adaptador_bluetooth.disable();
        }
        else
        {
          setImagenBluetooth(true);
            adaptador_bluetooth.enable();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        boolean FragmenTransaction= false;
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragment = new FragmentBlue();
            FragmenTransaction= true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if(FragmenTransaction)
        {
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).commit();
            item.setChecked(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lab02pc19.myapplication2.FragmentBlue">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivw"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_bluetooth"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickImagen"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imagen" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure this XML is `activity_main` ?

Comment: No, that XML is the FrameLayout, im going to post the XML file if you need it.

Comment: What happens if you change `if(valor) miimagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetooth);` to `if(valor) (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivw).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetooth);` will it work ?

Comment: No, dons´t work... if i change that the code look like this
 if(valor) (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivw).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetoot‌​h);
The "setImageResource" put in red, and if i press Alt+Intro, nothing happends.

Comment: I fixe it, but now I have this wrong
_ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick_
I have bad luck u.u ._.

Comment: Your code seems too complex. If you've fixed the previous error and getting new one. Then post that crash log as well. Like as above.

Comment: I'm sorry that I missed small bracket that's needed to be  `((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivw)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bluetoot‌​h);`

Answer (score 0):

As I think (it is not enough info), you want to create a fragment in the activity and make some actions with ImageView further. But you didn't create the fragment and try to find ImageView by id in other layout - thus, the image view didn't exist here, next you try to call function of the null object and finally have a NPE and crash. You need to read tutorial about  fragment in Android: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the image view of the fragment in your activity class which is not possible that's why giving null point exception. What you can do it that you can setImage in the image view in you fragment java class in onActivityCreated override method after setting the contentView.
If you want to set the image from the activity only then you can create the public method in the fragment and call the method from the activity.